# Why does this preg_match not return 1?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I've been looking at this code and it's supposed to match my $input string and in $matches[0] store 'testing'

```
$input = ':testing';
$r = preg_match('/^(?<=\:).+/',$input,$matches);
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(?<=)` is a positive look-*behind*, which means that the text matching the enclosed expression must occur *before* the position of the parenthetical in the pattern. In this case, it means it must occur after the start-of-string position (`^`), but before the first actual character (`.+` matches all of the characters in the string here), and since the `:` is the first actual character, and there's no `:` before the `:` (obviously), it fails to match.

Instead, what you probably want to do is use a *capture group*, like so:

```
$input = ':testing';
$r = preg_match('/^:(.+)/',$input,$matches);

// $matches[0] has the entire text matched by the pattern, ":testing"
// $matches[1] will now contain "testing" from the first capture
```

Thus you use `$matches[1]` to get the text from within the capture group, which is what you want.

Comment: Removing the `^` in the original regex could change the meaning and what is matched, Felix, since it would now partial-match on things like `"abc:testing"`, whereas the original regex very clearly was looking at whole strings only.

Comment: If you really needed the result to be in `$matches[0]` *and* for the match to be anchored, you could put the anchor inside the lookbehind: `/(?<=^:).+/`